# Should I switch my web site to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an web site built in ASP.NET. It is a business website that works with a lot of data.

I had a lot of problems, especially of speed and effectiveness, so I did what I can with ajax, and speed greatly improved.

I wonder if I should switch the web site to ASP.NET MVC?

I don't know ASP.NET MVC very deeply, so I want to know if I should invest in it, the main question is: Is ASP.NET MVC faster and more effective than regular ASP.NET?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? A quick search gave me a lot of results for performance comparisons between regular ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Just my two cents - I'd be tempted to concentrate more on improving the performance of the business processes that happen inside of the application over the web framework used. Have you performance profiled your application? Are the main hot points in framework code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that ASP.NET MVC is (if not, already has) becoming the mainstream way to develop websites in using the ASP.NET stack. There is a lot less emphasis on ASP.NET WebForms in the last few years, which hints that MVC is the sensible choice for starting new projects (Note: WebForms is still a popular choice for some devs though, I'm not saying don't use it ever. There's still a place for it.)

Regards migrating existing ASP.NET WebForms apps, I would be a little cautious. Don't switch to another technology unless you have a very, very good reason for doing so. Depending of factors such as the amount of code, the design, it could take a lot of effort to convert an ASP.NET WebForms project to ASP.NET MVC.

In your situation you mention performance issues, which made you consider moving to ASP.NET MVC. I would look more into why your site is not performing as you would like. Use a profiler to measure which code paths are taking the longest ot execute. There are plenty of sites built using ASP.NET WebForms which perform to high-scale, so I would not make the mistake of moving to another technology in order to solve a performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where your current issues are.

- Should you learn MVC - definitely.
- Should you write new applications in MVC - sure.
- Should you migrate old applications - depends.

What's the architecture of the current application?

How much time/resources do you have to allocate to a rewrite vs fire-fighting the existing app?

Is there a clear data or middle tier or is the data access built into each page code behind?  Many applications are written so that the front-end can be swapped easily or called from other applications (eg via an API) but many webforms applications (not all) are written without these considerations and so it wouldn't be a swap out but a complete rewrite of the application.

What are the current issues other than "it's a bit slow"?  For example I've seen an app that loaded the entire data model into memory for each page - simply changing the front-end would make no difference in this case as the cause of slowness was the data loading.  Changing the architecture to load only what was needed significantly increased the speed.

The improvements you can get from using MVC aren't necessarily the business level ones you might expect.  There are plenty of sites that go into this in more details, here's some to get you going:

- MVC generates (much) cleaner HTML in the output - so pages are easier to develop/maintain and easier for developing UI interactions in javascript.
- MVC has a much improved pipeline which can be hooked into, eg for adding action filters.
- IoC/DI is hugely easier in MVC
- Separates the model/controller code from the view html

Your application users won't care about any of these.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with one of my clients and after learning the MEAN stack and working with another company who made the transition to Nancy. I would recommend doing a REST API with Nancy and a pure front end with Angular or another Javascript front end. This will allow much faster response and flexibility down the road. Plus it will give you more flexibilty if you ever want to expose your API to other apps.

I tried to move from Web Forms to MVC and it was not very easy for me at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asp.net Web Forms, with more ajax and less post backs and less view state usage if you do not want to move to asp.net mvc.

Asp.net MVC on other hand is very good with light wight pages and capabilities to blend in with client side ajax based solutions. And its architecture supports scale ability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should definitely take the time to learn MVC, as it is becoming a more marketable skill and future projects are more likely to call for it.

With respect to being faster and more effective, it is somewhat. First off, WebForms have a lot of overhead in order to have this windows-forms-like behavior (which, frankly, has never been a perfect fit for web pages). Second, MVC tends to render HTML that is much cleaner without the view state or long IDs. So those two items can make it faster. (Of course, if you are having speed issues you also need to look hard at your host server.)

With respect to rewriting your current project to use MVC, that's a more difficult question that only you can answer. WebForms still work and will probably be supported by Visual Studio for many years to come. Depending on your project, rewriting it can be a costly task. So you'll need to decide if it's worth it. That said, I hope to rewrite all my webforms websites using MVC as time allows, although part of the reason is just to update the look and make them more responsive to mobile devices.

Comment: Side note: WebForms does not prevent responsive design. But using WebForms aspx designer may do so. As an example, see this [site](http://www.domainelaurentmartray.com), and compare to what is was [in wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140216233229/http://www.domainelaurentmartray.com/). It was and still is WebForms. Rather than rewriting it, it has been redesigned.

Comment: To clarify my comments, I want to rewrite the sites because I'd like to make them more modern and responsive, but I want to rewrite them using MVC because I like MVC better. I could make them more responsive with WebForms but prefer not to.